# Self-contained App with Spark-scala-Sbt

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I worked a project with Spark-scala ( system of recommandation), I have a problem when execute the my App. by spark-submit, it dispaly an exception.
My directories is : projectFilms/src/main/scala/AppFilms.scala
I compiled it by sbt package, it's fine successful and it create a file jar.

```
[info] Set current project to system of recommandation (in build file:/root/projectFilms/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /root/projectFilms/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /root/projectFilms/target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 35 s, completed Nov 22, 2016 7:31:59 PM
```

But when I ecxecute my App by Spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --class "AppFilms" --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar
```

he display an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppFilms
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:634)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/11/22 19:32:33 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Please can you answer me!

Comment: Could you please open your jar with some ZIP File Manager and check is there is AppFilms.class?

Comment: How I can open it ?

Comment: Right click on JAR and use for example `Open with 7-ZIP` or other application that allows to open ZIP files. You can also change extension to ZIP and open it

Comment: What class(es) do you have defined in `AppFilms.scala`? Regarding opening the JAR: `less target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar` should work, if not, then `unzip -l target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !

Comment: But I resolved the problem, it was just the name of my appli write it in small letter appFilms instead of AppFilms !